# does AdvancedTomato Web Monitor 'Monitor Web Usage' also log HTTPS traffic?

Tags: router, https, monitoring, tomato, network-traffic

I enabled this

[image]

Here some example logs:

```
zcat domain-201.....log.tar.gz
(..)
2017-05-03 00:19:29 192.168.1.23    update.appwork.org
2017-05-03 05:49:17 192.168.1.23    img.youtube.com
2017-05-03 17:39:58 192.168.1.23    ocsp.godaddy.com
2017-05-03 18:11:07 192.168.1.23    ocsp.comodoca.com
2017-05-03 18:21:04 192.168.1.23    ocsp2.globalsign.com
2017-05-03 19:10:53 192.168.1.23    detectportal.firefox.com
2017-05-03 19:46:48 192.168.1.23    ocsp.digicert.com
2017-05-03 23:16:56 192.168.1.23    clients1.google.com
(..)
```

How does this logging works exactly? Does he really logs everything? I see very small logs (expect much more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It logs only HTTP traffic. I monitored my desktop's traffic with [ntopng](https://github.com/ntop/ntopng) and saw that all HTTPS traffic doesn't appear in Tomato logs.

> ntopng is a web-based network traffic monitoring application released
>   under GPLv3. It is the new incarnation of the original ntop written in
>   1998, and now revamped in terms of performance, usability, and
>   features.

I use for example a Twitter client which constantly streams via HTTPS. In Tomato logs no connection to Twitter visible.